# Let $f$ continous and satisfies that $\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t) dt= x^2(x+1)$ calculate f(2)

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ continous and satisfies that $\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t) dt= x^2(x+1)$. Calculate f(2)

Here's my answer, and I want to know if it's correct

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x^2}f(t) dt= f(x^2) \cdot 2x  $$

On the other hand:

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x^2}f(t) dt= 2x(x+1)+x^2  $$

Then

$$ f(x^2) \cdot 2x= 2x(x+1)+x^2 \Longrightarrow f(x^2)= (x+1)+\frac{x}{2}$$

Therefore:
$$ f(2)= (\sqrt{2}+1)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x^2}f(t) dt= x^2(x+1)$ only makes sense if you have the restrition that $x \ge 0$ as you can sub in e.g. $1$ and $-1$ to get $0=\int_{0}^{1}f(t) dt= 2$

Comment: @B.Martin I'm agree with that!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you answer is correct. Notice how you got the form
$$f(x^2) = (x+1)+ \frac x2$$

This allows you to know that

$$f(t) = (\sqrt{t} + 1) + \frac{\sqrt{t}}{2}$$

This means I can just input this command into wolfram alpha

```
integrate  (sqrt(t)+1)+ 0.5*sqrt(t) dt from 0 to x^2
```

Then the output is easily manipulated into the original identity.

Doing stuff like this is a great way to check your answer if you are unsure, and I really recommend doing it as much as possible

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the recommendation!